# Is there any way to get rid of the "Pattern Not Found" error message?

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-plugin

I'm using YouCompleteMe on MacVim, and it's showing this message with pretty much every keystroke. Is there any way to suppress this error message specifically? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In particular, older Vim versions do not allow to cancel custom *insert-mode completion* silently via special return values -2 and -3 returned by `'completefunc'`. This feature has been specifically included for plugins like YouCompleteMe.

Comment: Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in the latest versions of Vim, I'm using version 7.4.383 now and the issue has been resolved.